# How to limit total number of inputs to textExt plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-textext

```
<textarea id="Responsible" rows="1"> </textarea>

$('#Responsible').textext({
      plugins : 'tags autocomplete',
      tagsItems : tempRrespArray
}).bind('getSuggestions', function(e, data) {
      var list = resAray,
      textext = $(e.target).textext()[0],
      query = (data ? data.query : '') || '';

      $(this).trigger('setSuggestions', 
                       {result : textext.itemManager().filter(list, query)});
});
```

This is my code. I want to limit the total number of inputs to one. At present it will accept n number of inputs. How to achieve this in textExt plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if this is the right way or not. But this worked for me. You can overwrite the core function using `ext` provided by the plugin and by having an additional function to check the elements already in the plugin. Your Plugin initialization should look like this

```
$('#element').textext({
    plugins : 'tags autocomplete',
    tagsItems : Sourcearray,
    ext: {
        tags: {
            addTags: function(tags) {
                if(checkLength()) {
                    $.fn.textext.TextExtTags.prototype.addTags.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

and the checkLength function should be like this

```
function checkLength(){
    if($("#element").next().children().length === 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Nice one!

One small caveat - $('#element').next() seems a bit unsafe for me. Newer version or a plugin for TextExt might break this.

Instead, you might use tagElements:
`if ($('#element').textext()[0].tags().tagElements().length === 0)`