# jQuery TextExt: max height and scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-textext

I'm using the jQuery TextExt plugin (http://textextjs.com/) to create an input field where the user can enter languages as tags, similar to the Facebook way of entering Tags.

Overall, the plugin works great.

However, I have hit a snag, which I can't seem to overcome. I am using TextExt on an Input field, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#id_languages').textext({
    plugins : 'tags prompt suggestions arrow autocomplete',
    tagsItems : ['English'],
    suggestions : languages, //variable set earlier
    prompt : 'Add more here...',
});
</script>
```

Which works as it should. Now, the more tags I add, the more the input field grows (as expected).

However, at some point, it grows beyond the height that is acceptable in my given layout.

Is there a working way of specifying the max height of the input element using TextExt, plus adding a vertical scrollbar, without having the Suggestions dropdown pop up inside the div with the scrollbar?

I hope that makes sense, I'm a bit confused myself at the moment.

Comment: can you create a http://www.jsfiddle.com for that?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm... not sure? How can I include the TextExt plugin in JsFiddle?

Comment: On the left-hand side, 3rd option is "External Resources", you put there the path to the plugin...

Comment: Hmm, I was asking because I tried adding the TextExt plugin from a CDN, but I can for the life of me not get it to do anything. See: [http://jsfiddle.net/8hPtY/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/8hPtY/2/). Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I should note that this is only the .js part.. The CSS is missing - I can't find it hosted anywhere. It shouldn't be needed at the moment though, at least not as long as the .js isn't working.

Comment: I've got that running on my machine, question: were you able to make it work with the Suggestions dropdown popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the source code, and there's no place it can be changed in order to accomplish what you need without a hack.

The closest answer to that is to limit the number of tags per input, which can be 
done like described here: [How to limit total number of inputs to textExt plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289680/how-to-limit-total-number-of-inputs-to-textext-plugin)

```
   $('#id_languages').textext({
                plugins : 'tags autocomplete',
                tagsItems : Sourcearray,
                ext: {
                   tags: {
                     addTags: function(tags) {
                         if(checkLength()) {
                            $.fn.textext.TextExtTags.prototype.addTags.apply(this, arguments);
                         }
                     }
                   }
                 }
   });
```

and here's the validation function `checkLength()`:

```
function checkLength(){
   if($("#id_languages").next().children().length < 4){
      return true;
   }
  return false;
}
```

Where the number 4 is the number of tags allowed.

If this wouldn't be satisfactory, you will have to hack into `textext.core.js` and `textext.plugin.tags.js` and look for the following functions:

`invalidateBounds()`, `preInvalidate()`  and `postInvalidate()` and play with the height manipulation.

Comment: Thank you! I feared this was the case, as I came to the same conclusion. I ended up limiting it to 10 tags and creating a JS/CSS hack to limit the size of the div(s) to a certain size. Not pretty at all, but it works for now.